# Conditional component render based on route in next js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, router

is there a way to conditionally render components based on URL in next.js?

Edit:

as if now, I'm doing this:

```
const router = useRouter();

return (
  <>
    <SomeComponent />
    {router.pathname === "/somePath" && <RenderThis />}
  </>
)
```

I'm wondering if there's a better/cleaner way to this conditional render? like...

```
<>
  <SomeComponent />
  <Route path="/additionalUrl" component={RenderThis} />
</>

//or

<>
  <SomeComponent />
  <Route path="/additionalUrl">
     <RenderThis />
  </Route>
</>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? You can use Router object returned by useRouter hook to get the query variables.
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: I edited the question. it's much more specific now.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this?  Conditionally rendering a certain component in another page based on the url path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style of your second example is reminiscent of React Router, so I can see where you're coming from.

However, in Next.js, filesystem based routing is implemented, and routing is handled for you based on the filename in the `/pages` directory.

If you are handling many different query parameters in your URLs, Next.js handles that as well, using [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

From the above linked docs:

Consider the following page `pages/post/[pid].js`:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>
}

export default Post
```

Any route like `/post/1`, `/post/abc`, etc. will be matched by `pages/post/[pid].js`. The matched path parameter will be sent as a query parameter to the page, and it will be merged with the other query parameters.

Comment: dynamic routing `/[pid].js` does or doesn't render the whole page based on the url. I already use this for many of my pages. I just don't know how to reander a specific component in a page (popup ect) based on the url.